# TinyMCE 4 remove/add attributes for all images

Tags: jquery, javascript, tinymce

i want to search for all images that have been add to TinyMCE 4 and:

1. Remove the height attribute from the images
2. Add style="max-width: 100%;" to all images

   - what is the best way to do this tasks?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your TinyMCE4 container has an id of 'tiny-mce-4', you could add this js to your `functions.php`.

```js
function toArray (collection) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(collection);
}

var imgs = toArray(document.querySelectorAll('#tiny-mce-4 img'));


imgs.forEach(function(img){
    img.setAttribute('style', img.getAttribute('style').replace(/((height:).*?(px;))/g, 'max-width: 100%;'));
});
```

```html
<div id="tiny-mce-4">

  <img src="img1" style="height: 500px; width: 800px;" />
  <img src="img2" style="height: 500px; width: 800px;" />
  <img src="img3" style="height: 500px; width: 800px;" />
  <img src="img4" style="width: 800px;" />

</div>

  <img src="img5" style="height: 500px; width: 800px;" />
```